# sumif(s), sumproduct for many to many relationship

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am looking for a formula/function that will allow me to essentially SUMIF(s) across a BOM. I know my part to FG relationship (Part, FG) and I know how many FG's I need(FG, Qty).

How can I calculate the number of parts I need (Part, Qty) in one step? Currently I am having to SUMIF each part/FG relationship (Part, FG, Qty and then SUMIF each part (Part, Qty).

I would like to do it in one step if possible.

[image]

Comment: saying i have to have 10 reputation points to attach a picture

Comment: saying i have to have 10 reputation points to attach a picture

Comment: here is the link
http://imgur.com/q7z8gbq

Comment: Does your second table need to have dates across the top? Can you have a date column so that your columns are: `FG, Date, Qty` instead?

Comment: FG, Date, Qty would be fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array formula to solve this (also known as a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> formula).

The first thing to do is manipulate your second table so that there is a date column in its own right. (It's generally best to avoid having information held in your column headers.)

I've used [Tables](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/09/10/data-tables/) (Insert > Table) so it's a bit easier to read the formula.

[image]

Now in cell I2 we can calculate the quantity for Part X on 7/11/14.

```
{=SUM(
   SUMIFS(Table2[Qty]
        ,Table2[Date]
        ,I$1
        ,Table2[FG]
        ,IF(Table1[Part]=$H2,Table1[FG])
        )
    )}
```

Remove the curly `{}` brackets before typing this in, and make sure you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when entering this formula.

Copy and paste this formula into cells I3, J2 & J3 to get the other values.

---

**Non-Table Version of the same formula**

```
{=SUM(
   SUMIFS($F$2:$F$9
        ,$E$2:$E$9
        ,I$1
        ,$D$2:$D$9
        ,IF($A$2:$A$7=$H2,$B2:$B$7)
        )
    )}
```